# Creating a list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples, append

I am a given an input file with values of data to read from, the data is given in a pair of numbers like:
(1, 2), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4,9) ..etc.

I must read each of these lines and make each line into a tuple and store the tuples in a list.

So far my code to do this is

```
def main():
tuples_list = []
    for item in sys.stdin:
        item = tuple(item)
        tuples_list = tuples_list.append(item)
```

However I have to ignore the first number in the input file and I am confused on how to modify my code to only start storing the values after that

Comment: The question "Will this work?" can be solved by running the code.

Comment: Your "pair" of numbers is *six* numbers?

Answer (score 0):

No, this wont work. You shouldnt do `a = a.append(b)`, just `a.append(b)`. This works:

```
# file '1.py'
import sys

def main():
    tuples_list = []
    for item in sys.stdin:
        item = tuple(item)
        tuples_list.append(item)
    print(tuples_list)
main()
```

```
#file 'inp.txt'
1 2 3 4 
1 2 4 3
3 3 3 3
```

```
$ python 1.py <inp 
[('1', ' ', '2', ' ', '3', ' ', '4', ' ', '\n'), ('1', ' ', '2', ' ', '4', ' ', '3', '\n'), ('3', ' ', '3', ' ', '3', ' ', '3', '\n')]
```

But, in my opinion, using self-written procedures for file input is a bad idea. As you can see, this code reads characters, not numbers, so you need to fix it manualy, which leads to more code, with bugs, of course, debugging, waste of time, etc.  You may want to do instead something like this:

```
# file inp.txt
1,2
3,4
5,6
```

```
import numpy as np
data = np.genfromtxt("inp.txt", delimiter=",")
print(data)
```

This will give you:

```
array([[1., 2.],
       [3., 4.],
       [5., 6.]])
```

This code is <s>way faster than anything you will write</s>(no, see comments below), because it uses numpy functions written in C/Fortran, way simpler to read, it handles any number of digits in line, and need no debugging. Using libraries are often better solution then writing code by yourself.

Comment: Please show your benchmark demonstrating that "This code is way faster ...", because in [my benchmark](https://repl.it/@sp0/read-pairs#main.py), it's about four times *slower*.

Comment: Hmm, strange. I have the following [results](https://pastebin.com/hvjYcUb3) on my machine. The difference is *very* large, as you see, so I even stoped pure python version in 1m23s, and numpy is way faster then pure python. But in your benchmark code without numpy is faster. May it be because you use `map` and `line.split()` which are optimized and written in C, too?

Comment: How does your `1.py` look like?

Comment: Ah, I see. Probably what you have in your answer. Which reads from `sys.stdin`. And you're not entering anything, so of course the code doesn't do anything. You waited for 1m23s for the code to finish while the code was waiting for you to give it some data.

Comment: oh, my bad. Just checked it - yes, i forgot to add `< inp`. And with correct input this code really runs slower, you were right.

Comment: Just to be sure: For a reading benchmark, the printing should be removed (especially since the numpy one only shows a small part of the whole data).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input file looks something like this:
[image]

```
import sys

def main():
    num = sys.stdin.readline()

    # Removing parantheses
    num = num.replace('(', '').replace(')', '')

    # creating list from input
    ls = [int(x) for x in num.split(',')]

    # Sublisting current list to form list of tuples
    sub = []
    tuples_ls = []

    for i in ls:
        sub += [i]
        
        if len(sub) == 2:
            tuples_ls.append(tuple(sub))
            sub = []

    return tuples_ls
```

Comment: Would this code do the same?   def main():
    num = int(sys.stdin.readline())
    for line in num:
        num = line.rstrip()
        ls = [int(line) for line in num.split(', ')]
        tuple_ls = tuple(ls)
    print(tuple_ls)

Comment: @zenag, you cannot define input type as an int and put ',' or ' '. First take it as str then process it to int with correct formatting.

Comment: How do i process it into an int? I dont understand? wasn't that this line "ls = [int(i) for i in str.split(', ')]
    return tuple(ls)
"

Comment: @zenag I edited answer, check if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Hello I figured it out thanks for your help!